# Using WebSVN link for Maven SCM URL

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin, websvn

A typical WebSVN link looks like this:

```
http://demo.websvn.info/listing.php?repname=WebSVN&path=%2Ftrunk%2F&#a0b40758157c8f16fa703ca3be466fa8a
```

But if you include that as your Maven scm/url, attempting to run a build (or more specifically for me - site:deploy) fails on the second '=' (equals) as per the following error:

```
[ERROR]   The project  (C:\Subversion\MyProject\pom.xml) has 1 error 
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM C:\Subversion\MyProject\pom.xml: entity 
reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG     
seen ...ttp://mysvnserver.com/SVN/websvn/listing.php?repname=MyProject&path=... 
@510:81)  @ line 510, column 81 -> [Help 2]
```

Is there a workaround for this, to allow the use of WebSVN in published Maven sites?

Comment: An ampersamp should be correctly given in XML like &amp;

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work. WebSVN if your human interaction only. You need to provide developer connection to the real repo.

Comment: Under scm, there are three types: "url", "connection" and "developerConnection".  I provide the developer connection under that last one.  My post above was in regard to providing a readable link for non-developers, which is what "url" is for (according to the way it is presented via maven-site-plugin.